# Opening Multiple Workbooks with shortcut key

Tags: excel, vba

This code fails (no code runs) after opening the first workbook from the object list. This occurs in the code after `Dim obj, rng As Range`.

The code is designed to take the values from specific columns and create separate workbooks for any values that exist in an array (MyArray).

I use a shortcut key "Ctrl + Shift + (letter key)" to activate the macro.

```vb
Sub RemoveViolationIDs()

Dim fbook As Workbook
Dim fBook2 As Workbook
Dim fpath As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim d As Object, c As Range, k, tmp As String
Dim fname As String
Dim fname2 As String
Dim copies As New Collection

MyArray = Array("ALTERPOINT_SBC", "FWSECADM", "ARCSIGHT_PAN_PCAP", "PANSECADM", "CPSECADM", "FSSECADM", "TP21ADMIN", "RADMON", "RADMON_NA")

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
fname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
fSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
fpath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Set fbook = ActiveWorkbook

Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    
If InStr(1, fname, "swpaSumRPT", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
    For fRow = lastRow To 4 Step -1
        If Not IsInArray(UCase(Cells(fRow, 2).Value), MyArray) = True Then Cells(fRow, 2).EntireRow.Delete
    Next
ElseIf InStr(1, fname, "swpaViolRPT", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
    For fRow = lastRow To 4 Step -1
        If Not IsInArray(UCase(Cells(fRow, 4).Value), MyArray) = True Then Cells(fRow, 4).EntireRow.Delete
    Next
End If
ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
If InStr(1, fname, "swpaSumRPT", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
    For Each fCell In ActiveSheet.Range("B4:B" & lastRow)
        fCell = UCase(Trim(fCell.Value))
        fname2 = Replace(fpath & "\" & fname, "swpaSumRPT-", "swpaSumRPT-" & fCell & "-")
        fbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:L3").AutoFilter , field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & fCell, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        wbTest = ""
        wbTest = Dir(fname2)
        If wbTest = "" Then fbook.SaveCopyAs fname2
        copies.Add fname2
    Next fCell

ElseIf InStr(1, fname, "swpaViolRPT", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
    For Each fCell In ActiveSheet.Range("D4:D" & lastRow)
        fCell = UCase(Trim(fCell.Value))
        fname2 = Replace(fpath & "\" & fname, "swpaViolRPT-", "swpaViolRPT-" & fCell & "-")
        fbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:L3").AutoFilter , field:=4, Criteria1:="<>" & fCell, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        wbTest = ""
        wbTest = Dir(fname2)
        If wbTest = "" Then fbook.SaveCopyAs fname2
        copies.Add fname2
    Next fCell

End If

Dim obj, rng As Range
    For Each obj In copies
        MsgBox ("Now Opening " & obj)
        Set fBook2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(obj)
        ' avoid header 3 rows
        Set rng = fBook2.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(3)
        ' delete visible rows
        rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        fBook2.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:L3").AutoFilter ' remove filter
    Next obj
    
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
'******
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
Dim i
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i) = stringToBeFound Then
        IsInArray = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i
IsInArray = False

End Function
```

Comment: What does "fail" mean? Error message?

Comment: @BigBen No code is recognized after the open command.  I've tried to trigger it with MsgBox commands, but the sub simply stops running.

Comment: First, I'd do `Dim copies As Collection`, `Set copies = New Collection`. Then check `copies.Count` to make sure the collection actually includes items.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this whole thing is because I used a shortcut key "Ctrl + Shift + (letter key)" to activate the macro.  I wasn't aware that this could cause such problems.  Removing "Shift" from the shortcut key solves the issue that I was having.  Thanks to everyone who answered my question earlier.  I appreciate all your insight.